# Object is of type 'unknown'. ts(2571) with Vuejs and Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

So I am trying to store JSON data in a variable in a Vue project.

The code to upload and store the file is

`<input type="file" id="file" ref="fileSelect" class="custom-file-input" @change="showfiles" />`

```
<script lang="ts">
.
.
methods: {
showfiles() {
    let files = this.$refs.fileSelect.files //Error Object is of type 'unknown'. ts(2571) 
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = ({ target: { result }}) => { this.p = JSON.parse(result); };
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
    console.log(this.p) //I am storing JSON data in p
}}
```

I searched online and found various fixes but none of them are working for me
I tried adding  `"useUnknownInCatchVariables": false` to tsconfig, it fixes the error momentarily but the error comes back.
I also tried `try and catch`

```
showfiles() {
      try{
        let files = this.$refs.fileSelect.files
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = ({ target: { result }}) => { this.p = JSON.parse(result); };
        reader.readAsText(files[0]);
        console.log(this.p)
      }
      catch(err) {
        if (err instanceof Error) { 
      console.log(err.message);
    } else {
      console.log('Unexpected error', err);
    }
}
    }
```

But none of these worked.
I'll greatly appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You didn't type `fileSelect` ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to cast the type of `fileSelect` ref yourself like that:

```
showfiles() {
  const files = (this.$refs.fileSelect as HTMLInputElement).files // const files: FileList | null
    // ...
  }
```

I guess you are not reading the result correctly. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) you should just take the result from filereader's `result` property.

```
reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
  this.p = JSON.parse(reader.result);
}, false);
```

Comment: Now I am getting an error in the next lines
```reader.onload = ({ target: { result }}) => { this.p = JSON.parse(result); };``` Property 'result' does not exist on type 'FileReader | null'.ts(2339) and in line ```reader.readAsText(files[0]);``` Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Comment: That was not clear from your question.

Comment: Try to access the result like that: ```reader.onload = () => { this.p = JSON.parse(reader.result); }```

Comment: I wasn't getting these errors before, I got them after I cast the type of ```fileSelect```.

Comment: And also why are you using filereader's ```readAsText``` method instead of ```readAsDataURL``` ?

Comment: Cause I want to use the data loaded in **p** in other functions, plus my end goal is create a table using the JSON data and display it.

Comment: You are welcome!:) Please, mark my post as an answer if it really helped)